# iOS - "Lock" rotation for a while

Tags: ios, ipad, rotation, selector

I need to lock the rotation for a specific view for a while. I explain it better. I have a button and when it is pressed I start a process. During that process I need the rotation is disabled.. how can I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the user presses a button, you have to fix what you are returning from

```
-(NSUInteger) supportedInterfaceOrientations
```

for the duration you want.